# paypal advanced configuration woocommerce

Tags: authentication, paypal, woocommerce

I bought woocommerce paypal advanced but I don't know how to configure it here is the things I had done:

1. created paypal sandbox account
2. created seller account and marked it as pro
3. created buyer account

then I added merchant login in admin (sellers email)

mark sandbox on.

than when I try to buy product from front end I get error

> Error: "There was an error processing your order - User authentication failed"

I don't know what further steps requires?

is there any manager.paypal.com registration required.

I need detail guide to setup it woocommerce paypal advanced

is is it necessary to create account with manager.paypal.com? if yes than is it free to create and test like sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

This service uses PayPal Manager, sign in at https://manager.paypal.com

**It is recommended to set up another PayPal Manager user for use with your account as you may be prompted monthly to change the root user account and would then have to change it in the WooCommerce settings as well.**

*Important Steps:*

1.Installing PayPal Payments Advanced

2.Signing up for PayPal Payments Advanced

3.Signing up for a Test Account

4.WooCommerce Configuration

5.PayPal Manager Configuration

**Detailed Steps are mentioned** [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/paypal-payments-advanced/)..